# Log within whole program

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core

How do I log everywhere in the program, without having to declare ILogger parameter in every class? I would like best practice to log everywhere within program.

```
MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}
```

Should I [utilize a static class as described here](https://stackify.com/net-core-loggerfactory-use-correctly/)?

```
public class ApplicationLogging
{
    private static ILoggerFactory _Factory = null;

    public static void ConfigureLogger(ILoggerFactory factory)
    {
        factory.AddDebug(LogLevel.None).AddStackify();
        factory.AddFile("logFileFromHelper.log"); //serilog file extension
    }

    public static ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Factory == null)
            {
                _Factory = new LoggerFactory();
                ConfigureLogger(_Factory);
            }
            return _Factory;
        }
        set { _Factory = value; }
    }
    public static ILogger CreateLogger() => LoggerFactory.CreateLogger();
}
```

Comment: `without having to declare ILogger parameter in every class` What is your concern with doing this?

Comment: Take a look at PostSharp : http://doc.postsharp.net/add-logging

Comment: it seems kind of redundant to me, I have around 50+ classes in my program

Comment: Firstly, "*I would like best practice to log everywhere within program*" don't do that, not everything needs to log, you shouldn't need to be passing a logger to every class, unless this is all top level code. Secondly, the world these days has gone DI, and its very common to inject the logger in when you need it.

Comment: The main issue with using a `static` is that mocking the logger in unit tests is harder (which, in my mind, is a big issue). If that is not a concern for you, then go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not a good idea to use a logger a static dependency. Personally, I would inject it in the constructor of the class. Why? Well, static dependencies in form of a static property have the following problems:

- In the case of unit tests, they are hard to mock. If you inject the logger in the CTOR you can libs like Moq to change the logging to e.g. stdout (ok, that's also possible with e.g. log4net's config file).
- Using static properties can make your code "non-determistic". Why? A static property is initialized when the class is referenced the first time. So if you change your code the static property initialization may be called earlier or later. If you've  a bug in the initialization it will be hard to find. Why? Because you've no logging.
- If you want to change the logging framework, you've to find all static references to it. Ok, that's not a that hard task with grep or modern IDEs. However, if you inject the logger dependency the compiler will show (based on the compile errors) which lines of code you've to change (simply remove the logger reference from the solution file).

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, I guess I will pass it as a parameter in every class then, just wanted to confirm

Comment: Try to use dependency injection via a DI container like autofac (https://autofac.org/). Pro: if done correctly most parts of your classes are constructed in one place of your program.

Comment: @JoeThomas, if you're happy with above answer, please mark it as answer for your question. Thx